# Get the value of a cell, not the index

Tags: r

In R, my dataset paym_area has 3 rows which each represent a person and the columns contain the payments required by each person to enrol 3, 2, 1 and 0 units of area into a scheme. For each of these people, I've identified the column that contains the max area they are willing to enrol for the given payment rate (paym_sh1a) using:

`paym_3<-c(20,30,40)`

`paym_2<-c(12,32,34)`

`paym_1<-c(8,40,20)`

`paym_0<-c(0,0,0)`

`paym_area=cbind(paym_3,paym_2,paym_1,paym_0)`

`paym_sh1a=20`

`sums=apply(paym_area,1,function(x){x[x<=paym_sh1a]<-min(x);which.min(x)})`

so this gives me an output of "[1] 1 4 3"
But as well as the column index, I also want to know the value that is in each of those columns, how do I do this?
so I want an output of "[1] 20 0 20"

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `apply` code to :

```
apply(paym_area,1,function(x)max(x[x<=paym_sh1a]))
#[1] 20  0 20
```

Comment: thanks for this - but i think it doesn't work when the payment required by an individual declines as area increases, so if the threshold payment in my example, paym_sh1a, was increased to 40, everyone should enrol 3 units (and they do in my code), but your bit of code gives the answer " [1] 20 40 40"  but it should give " [1] 20 30 40"

Comment: Not sure what this means.